# A Künneth formula for relative fiber products

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, etale-cohomology

There is a Künneth formula for the cohomology of a product of spaces $X\times Y$ in quite a lot of generality.

Is there a Künneth formula for relative fiber products $X\times_S Y$? The case I am most interested in is $X,Y,S$ curves over a finite field and $\ell$-adic cohomology. It should express the cohomology of $X\times_S Y$ in terms of the cohomology of $X$, $Y$, and $S$ in some way (maybe a spectral sequence, maybe something else).

But I would be interested in such a formula in any other context too.

Comment: This is not going to work without sheaf cohomology. If the maps from $X$ and $Y$ to $S$ are proper (e.g. finite), or you work with compactly supported cohomology, then the cohomology of $X \times_S Y$ is the cohomology of the tensor product sheaf of the pushforward of the constant sheaf on $X$ and the pushforward of the constant sheaf on $Y$. The Kunneth formula is stated and proved this way in SGA.

Comment: Without sheaf cohomology, we can have $X = \mathbb P^1, Y = \mathbb P^1, S= \mathbb P^1$, and the cohomology of $X \times_S Y$ arbitrarily complicated.

Comment: In homotopy theory: you need one of the maps to be a fibration, or to take the homotopy pullback, for the result to be homotopy invariant. Then in the case of simply-connected S there is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Moore_spectral_sequence.